# Using android palette class in desktop java application

Tags: java, android

Android developers have created a great class to isolate colors from an image

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/palette/src/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.java

However I could really use this in a desktop application.  I tried ripping the class from the library (as recommended to me , during a Devox java conference by one of the android devs) but he probably didn't realize I would have to drag half of the android library with me then eg: Bitmap, Color

Does anyone know of a tool that might be able to strip the classes I need retroactivly from the library, or give me a better way to solve my original problem, a java class that will give me the dominant colors of an image together with their inverse and adjoining colors ?  I can't write it from scratch cause we just don't have the budget/time to do that :(

Comment: This article may help (suggested by alashow) https://chris.banes.me/2014/02/18/colour-matching/

Comment: fun fact though, I believe he was the guy that told me to rip it out of the library at devoxx :(

Comment: I took a peek for you, found a couple possibilities: [ColorLib](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/util/ColorLib.html) class in [prefuse visualization toolkit](http://prefuse.org/); [ColorPalette](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ColorPalette.html) class in [jFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). Both of these are, like the Android [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html), part of libraries which have a purpose that may or may not suit your current needs.

Comment: Thanks I'll give them a look

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question and I also found [this lightweight library on github](https://github.com/SvenWoltmann/color-thief-java) that is a port of one of the javascript libraries that Chris Banes references in the blog post mentioned above.

It's pretty good at extracting the primary color for images quickly.  I would still love it if someone had a way to extract something like what android calls the "vibrant" color.  Ideally I would love a way to mimic exactly what happens in the android library so i could have a seamless experience between my android, desktop, and ios experiences.  I still haven't found that one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another Java port - https://github.com/trickl/palette. I wrote this one myself (I was unaware of the existence of other ports at the time). It's a pretty direct port and includes a bunch of the original tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is [this `Palette` ported library](https://github.com/loyalsound/Iris). You can use it in your Gradle based java project by adding `jcenter()` to your repositories and the next dependency into your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.loyalsound:iris:1.1"
}
```